# How to replace gif logo with flash logo in magento?

Tags: magento

How to replace gif logo with flash logo in magento?

Comment: Could you expand on that a little? Convert an animated gif into flash format or just embedding flash in the place of gif?

Answer (score 4):

The logo is rendered by the `header.phtml` file in `app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/page/html`.  Edit line 32 (assuming you're using v1.4) that contains `<img src.../>` and replace it with your Flash embed codes.